# passing function pointer not working

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I have 2 libraries. Library A is compiled in C. Library B is compiled in C++, but it is mostly C code.

I need to call the following function in library A:

```
foo* c_func(int64_t (*ptr_to_func)(void));
```

The first thing this function does is:

```
if(!ptr_to_func)
  return NULL;
```

The ptr_to_func needs to point to a function in library B which is declared as:

```
int64_t bar(void);
```

I have a cpp file with a main function that calls another function, in there I do the following:

```
foo* f = c_func(bar);
```

Then I check if f is null. It is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  `foo` is a type, not a variable.  The result of `c_func(bar)` is based on whatever `c_func` does; you didn't provide its definition.  It might work but be returning `NULL` for some reason.

Comment: @Jeremiah Presumably the OP means that `f` is checked, rather than `foo`.

Comment: @Jim Yes, that was my intention. Sorry for the confusion. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing appears to be correct, with the caveat that your function `bar()` should be declared within an `extern "C" {` section.

`c_func()` is probably returning `NULL` for a different reason.  Step through it in the debugger and see (set a breakpoint at the beginning of `c_func()`).

Comment: Do I still need the extern if the header file containing the function bar also contains ifdef __cplusplus.

Comment: @anio: The function itself shouldn't be contained in the header file - only its declaration.  If you are compiling that function as C++, then both the declaration and definition should be within `extern "C" { }`.  The `#ifdef __cplusplus` is used to allow you to compile the same file as C, but you have said that you are compiling that library as C++, so this is probably not relevant.